# BeautifulSoup python ... soup.find(id="productTitle") does not return anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and would like to pull some information from amazon. I've wrote these few basic lines, but they are not working...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL ='https://www.amazon.ca/Monkey-Biscuits-14-oz-Orange/dp/B074SYBXLG/'

headers= {'User-Agent':  '...myuseragent' }

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
print( soup.find(id="productTitle") )
```

Yet the html file clearly has the below section:

```
<span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large">
Exotic Nutrition Monkey Biscuits 14 oz. (Orange) - Food for Old World Primates
</span>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: turn off JavaScript in browser and then load this page in browser - you will see what Python can see.

Comment: I am not really sure how to turn it off, I will try.
But I am pretty sure python can see what I see with javascript on because the html string is perfect and contain my string when I output it to a file..

Comment: Yup still seeing the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `"html.parser"` has problem to find it but it works if I use `"lxml"` - but it may means you have to install module `lxml`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

print(soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text(strip=True))
```

---

**EDIT:** works also with `"html5lib"` (if you have it installed)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

Comment: It worked with html5lib !
I prefer it over lxml for its simplicity 

many thnaks !

Comment: Do you have any idea why that is? It just seems bizarre.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile in documentation I found [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) and they may treat invalid HTML in different way - and maybe it can be explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile there is also table which compare [Advantages and Disadvantages](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) and some parsers are less restricted (lenient) for incorrect HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Some tag in html documents may generated by javascript dynamically.
By using BeautifulSoup, you can only **scrape** the static element.
Using selenium will free you from trouble.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html